# IonSearchbar inputmode="search" not working on iPhone

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I even tried embedding it with  tag, but still keypad in iPhone shows Return instead of Search.
Also how to get keyboard search click event?

Answer (score 0):

Check returnKeyType (textinput) documentation 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype

Comment: I am using ionic/react and not react native.